# web scraping problem , r not defined? how to fix?

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make an app that scrapes my top ten favorite space related stock prices. but

List item
I have some trouble with my code and I'm new to scraping. Once I get    this to work, I want to put it into a csv file and make a bar graph    with it, I would love some help and suggestions. Also Im doing this    in Anaconda :

```
#import libraries 
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
#grequests is a unique library that allows you to use many urls with ease
#must install qrequest in annacode use : conda install -c conda-forge grequests
#if you know a better way to do this, please let me know
import grequests

#scraping my top ten favorite space companies, attempted to pick compaines with pure play interest in space

urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILT/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LORL?p=LORL&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I?p=I&.tsrc=fin-srch' , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VSAT?p=VSAT&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN?p=RTN&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTX?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TDY?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ORBC?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPCE?p=SPCE&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA&.tsrc=fin-srch',]  
unsent_request = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)

results = grequests.map(unsent_request)
```

Next comes where the error seems to be:

```
def  parsePrice():
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
    price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
    return price

while True:
    print('current stock price: '+str(parsePrice()))
```

after this in anaconda this error appears:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-65e4abca95ee> in <module>
      1 while True:
----> 2     print('current stock price: '+str(parsePrice()))

<ipython-input-7-67b5742dffee> in parsePrice()
      1 def  parsePrice():
----> 2     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
      3     price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
      4     return price

NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

Also can you please tell me if this is the right way to put my code into a csv and with the columns I want:

```
#add to csv file 
df_indu = pd.DataFrame(
    L['Top Ten Space Stocks'],
    columns=['stock name', 'stock price', 'date of listing'])
df_indu.to_csv('spacestocks.csv', index=False, sep='|')
```

I am more concerned about the error right now, but both would be nice, thanks

Comment: with normal `requests` you should have `r = requests.get(url)` but with I don't know what you have in rest of code. Maybe you should have `def  parsePrice(r):` and run it as `parsePrice(request.get(url))`? or maybe you get `request.get(url)` with different name of variable. I don't know what you have in `unsent_request`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this one

```py
def  parsePrice(r):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
        price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
        return price

for r in results:
   parsePrice(r)
```

Comment: so I put that in but the code you gave me is getting this error:I              
ndexError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9ac8cb94b6fb> in <module>
      5 
      6 for r in results:
----> 7    parsePrice(r)

<ipython-input-6-9ac8cb94b6fb> in parsePrice(r)
      1 def  parsePrice(r):
      2         soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
----> 3         price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
      4         return price
      5 

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

You just didn't define the "r" variable or didn't pass it to the function.

```
#import libraries 
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
#grequests is a unique library that allows you to use many urls with ease
#must install qrequest in annacode use : conda install -c conda-forge grequests
#if you know a better way to do this, please let me know
import grequests

#scraping my top ten favorite space companies, attempted to pick compaines with pure play interest in space

urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILT/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LORL?p=LORL&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I?p=I&.tsrc=fin-srch' , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VSAT?p=VSAT&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN?p=RTN&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTX?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TDY?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ORBC?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPCE?p=SPCE&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA&.tsrc=fin-srch',]  
unsent_request = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)

results = grequests.map(unsent_request)

for r in results:
       parsePrice(r)

def  parsePrice(r):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
        price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
        return price
```

Comment: what would you add to my code to make it work? can you give me advice? thanks

Comment: Look at NikolayNedelchev solution.
It's the same thing I wrote but with code.

Comment: If Python tells you that 'r' is not defined, then, 'r' is not defined. Hurray Python! Please delete the question.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't really used `BeautifulSoup`. But it looks like you need to read a file. They call it `r` in your code and it is actually not declared anywhere.